# Yocto build crashing at gcc and hard fpu problem

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, cross-compiling, yocto

I'm currntly trying to build a yocto image and SDK for a custom board with MediaTek MT8167B (https://www.mediatek.com/products/tablets/mt8167b).

I'm having the latest yocto version (2.5.2), i've setup this in the local.conf :

```
MACHINE ?= "qemuarm"
TARGET_SYS = "arm-linux-gnueabihf"
TUNE_FEATURES = "arm armv7a cortexa7 vfpv4 neon"
TUNE_CCARGS_MFLOAT = "vfp"
TUNE_CCARGS_MFLOAT = "hard"
```

But before building, the build configuration show that the TARGET_FPU is still soft :

```
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.38.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-linux-gnueabihf"
MACHINE              = "qemuarm"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "2.5.2"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm armv7a cortexa7 vfpv4 neon"
TARGET_FPU           = "soft"
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "psc-2.5.2:95ebfb33e4c0aa9669f318e061a4d7540b84f4ac"
```

Then the build start and is crashing at this point :

```
| checking whether ln -s works... yes
| checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc...  /home/mggk/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gcc-cross-initial-arm/7.3.0-r0/gcc-7.3.0/build.x86_64-linux.arm-linux-gnueabihf/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/mggk/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gcc-cross-initial-arm/7.3.0-r0/gcc-7.3.0/build.x86_64-linux.arm-linux-gnueabihf/./gcc/ -B/home/mggk/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gcc-cross-initial-arm/7.3.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ -B/home/mggk/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gcc-cross-initial-arm/7.3.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/ -isystem /home/mggk/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gcc-cross-initial-arm/7.3.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include -isystem /home/mggk/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gcc-cross-initial-arm/7.3.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sys-include --sysroot=/home/mggk/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gcc-cross-initial-arm/7.3.0-r0/recipe-sysroot
| checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/home/mggk/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gcc-cross-initial-arm/7.3.0-r0/gcc-7.3.0/build.x86_64-linux.arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc':
| configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
| See `config.log' for more details.
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| Makefile:11175: recipe for target 'configure-target-libgcc' failed
| make: *** [configure-target-libgcc] Error 1
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/mggk/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gcc-cross-initial-arm/7.3.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.25969)
ERROR: Task (/home/mggk/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-cross-initial_7.3.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 138 tasks of which 80 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
```

To be honest, i have no idea of what makes it crash, clean Linux System (Ubuntu 18.04) and not other compiler installed.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

qemuarm in OE-Core is primarily a armv5te emulator, so the changes you have done wont make this work for a newer architecture.

I would suggest that you add something like [meta-qemuarma9](https://github.com/OverC/meta-qemuarma9) to your bblayers.conf and then set

MACHINE = "qemuarma9" and bake your SDK.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
Currently building sdk for a software and found this in the configure script :
source /usr/local/oecore-x86_64/environment-setup-cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi

So trying a lot of modifications on local.conf to makes it look like what i found in the configure.

I Still have the compiling error on compiling gcc-cross-initial.
Thanks fort your help !

Comment: If you want cortexa7 tuning, then you should use something like raspberrypi3 for MACHINE and add meta-raspberrypi to layer config.